# How can I animate a tile in a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, calayer, quartz-graphics

I need to create an animated chevron effect using the bitmap tile below. I am hoping that a `UIView` with a pattern fill will be sufficient, but I need to be able to animate the origin of the pattern over time, and I can't see that this is possible.

I think this is possible with `Quartz`, or `CoreGraphics` at the low level. What would be the best way to do this, and can you provide some example code in Swift that demonstrates the solution?

[image: The tile that I would like to animate]

Comment: Your question is both too broad and too vague to be a good fit. Yes, you could animate using a custom UIView and core Graphics. You could also use Core Animation.

Comment: I will edit my question to make it clear what I am asking for here.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the image as contents of multiple sublayers ([`CALayer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer) instances) aligned one below the other and animate those sublayers y position.

The main layer would clip its sublayers on the border and sublayers that go offscreen would move to the bottom to be reused, similarly to how [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview) reuses its cells.

You might also want to look at [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) to have better control of  the rendering.